# KafkaConsumer poll time slicing behavior for pattern matching consumer group

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Lets say we have 2 instances of pattern matching KafkaConsumers (say C1, C2) subscribing to the same groupId. Overall we have 10 topics with single partitions (say T1 to T10). In this configuration, let say topics T1 to T5 got assigned to KafkaConsumer C1 and topics T6 to T10 got assigned to KafkaConsumer C2.

max.poll.records value is 10 on the KafkaConsumer side.

Messages are being produced with different rates into these different topics. Say T1, T5, T6 & T10 have message incoming rate of 200 messages per second and other topics have message incoming rate of 50 messages per second.

I want to know the behavior of poll operation in this case, how does the KafkaConsumer fetches the messages from different topics in this case where different topics have different message incoming rates.

Does it fetch the messages from different topics in a round robin fashion?

Or it intelligently detects that for some topics since the number of pending messages are high, the consumer.poll starts fetching the messages for these topics more frequently?